# Limit & Order By Random not showing correct result

Tags: php, mysql

i have query like this

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from tenant where totalrating>=".$jum." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,".$limit2."");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * from preorder where id_tenant='".$row['id_tenant']."' and id_acara='$idacara'");
   while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
   {
       echo row['order'];
   }
}
```

I have variable `$limit` to set my limit, and my problem is if i set limit 5, the result just show 4 data, if i refresh the page, the result will show 5 data, if i refresh the page again, the result show 4 again. Can someone give me an explanation about this? 
Thank you and have a nice day!!

Comment: I think, ur query is ok.

Comment: Your query looks fine. Please print out the variables `$limit2` and `$jum` and print something inside the first `while`. You might just have no results for `$result2`;

Comment: $limit2 = 5 and $jum=3. My goal is i want to get data with totalrating >=3 and limit just 5 data

Answer (score 0):

When you are using:

```
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,".$limit2.""
```

Then you are getting random records each time, so, may some of them don't have corresponding records in ***preorder*** table.

I suggest your to add another line to your code to make sure you are getting 5 results always

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from tenant where totalrating>=".$jum." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,".$limit2."");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "<br />Getting results preorders of id_tenant=". $row['id_tenant'] . " and idacara=$idacara <br />";

   $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * from preorder where id_tenant='".$row['id_tenant']."' and id_acara='$idacara'");
   while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
   {
       echo row['order'];
   }
}
```

That way you can note you are always getting 5 results, with some of them has no records in ***preorder*** table